# Global Variables not updated due to load balancing

Tags: java, load-balancing, haproxy

There are two servers running a web service and the servers are load balanced using HAProxy.

Web Service does a post and updates a global variable with a certain value and another application running on the same servers will read this global value and does some processing.

My issues is when I set the value to gloabl variable using the web service; due to the load balancer only one server's gets updated. Due to this, application some times read the global value and when the request goes to the second server it wont read it as the global variable is not updated in that server.

Can someone tell me  how to handle a situation like this. Both the web service and the application is Java based.

Comment: You could use a database that can be accessed from both servers to store all your global data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, relying on global data is probably a bad idea.  A better solution would be to persist the data in some common store, such as a database or a (shared) Redis cache.  Second, you could - if necessary - use sticky sessions on the load balancer so that subsequent requests always return to the same web server, as long as it is available.  The latter qualification is one of the reasons why a shared cache or database solution should be preferred - the server may go down for maintenance or some other issue during the user's session.

Comment: Thank you both . I agree that storing the value in a global variable is not a good practice. Will go for the sticky session approach